# Batch type file with variables

Tags: variables, batch-file, echo

i have a text file file.txt with the content:

> %hello%

If i've set hello to "holi" is there any way I can type file.txt and resolve the variable content?

Maybe it's archivable piping to echo but

> type file.txt | echo

Is not working for me.

Any help will be apreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what do you want to do and what is your issue? What does it mean that you set hello to "holi". What do you mean by resolving variable content?

Comment: @kaskader - Fradantim has an environment variable named `hello` with a value of `holi`. He wants to write the content of the file, but have variable names within percents to be expanded.

Comment: thanks  @dbenham, much clearer now!  it would be great if you could rewrite the question to make it easier to understand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there are no blank lines that need to be preserved

```
for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("yourFile.txt") do call echo(%%A
```

If there are blank lines, but no line begins with `:`, then

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "yourFile.txt"') do call echo(%%B
```

If there are blank lines, and some lines begin with `:`, and there are no `!` literals

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "yourFile.txt"') do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  call echo(!ln:*:=!
)
```

If there are blank lines and some lines begin with `:`, and there are `!` literals

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "yourFile.txt"') do (
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "ln=%%A"
  call echo(!ln:*:=!
  endlocal
)
```

All of the above use CALL, which slows things down considerably. The solution is faster if you put `!hello!` in your file instead of `%hello%`, and then you can rely on delayed expansion to expand the variable.

If no blank lines

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("yourFile.txt") do echo(%%A
```

If blank lines, but no line begins with `:`

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "yourFile.txt"') do echo(%%B
```

If blank lines, and some lines begin with `:`

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "yourFile.txt"') do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  echo(!ln:*:=!
)
```

Comment: Thanks! This was just what I was looking for! Your 3rd example worked just awesome. Thanks for answering so fast.

Answer (score 3):

So I take it you want the contents of a file to be expanded just like variables.

Here you go:

```
>echo %hello%>file.txt

>type file.txt
%hello%

>set hello=holi

>type file.txt
%hello%

>for /f %f in (file.txt) do @echo %f
%hello%

>for /f %f in (file.txt) do @call echo %f
holi

>
```

Comment: Thanks for understandig and answering so fast. This is a great answer, but it won't work for me if the file contains lines with more than only the variable, like "a%hello%" or "a %hello%" or "%hello% a". Sory, I should have said this.

Comment: @Fradantim I tried it and it does work, at least in the situations you've mentioned. However, it doesn't work with blank lines - in that respect, dbenham gave you the better answer.